# Handling timeout for multi players games in node js.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, redis

I am writing down server for a chess game in which events are organised and thousands of players will participate in an event and we will create match among 2 players i.e if 1000 players it means 500 matches and in match user has limited time to play his turn his N turns if timed out server will play turns on behalf of this user. In case if play close game in-between, we still need to complete the game.

My problem here is how to manage remaining time and getting information of a player who is timed out.

Can someone suggest me what should  be the best way to handle these kind of games.

Comment: I see that you put sockets as tags, so I consider that you know how to use them, you simply keep connection with user, you must have timer on server. Tho I don't understand why you want to continue game when time runs out because that is 1 of conditions for ending game, same if player closes game, tho You could have some kind of "pause"  if 1 player disconnects because he might have issue and come back.

Comment: Thanks @FilipRistic 
Yes, I have an idea about sockets but we can't rely on the client side as the user has an option to came back to the game by pressing `I am back button` in that case he can play his remaining turn.

Currently, I am using a mongodb-cron[https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-cron] module. And it query DB frequently to check if there is a time passed when the user has not played his turn. But I am not sure is it efficient to query DB every second or less.

And what do you mean by timers on the server for thousands or lack of user?

Comment: And there could be a chance that he didn't open his app when event stated until event finished but we need to finish his game with the opponent by playing his turn with random moves.

Comment: Those are all now implementation details, you will need to find out what fits your needs best, I just gave you an idea.

Comment: thanks @FilipRistic. Anybody else who can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)